# Trying to click a website button with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I wonder if anyone can please help me.

I am trying to use AppleScript to click the buy now button on

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guinness-World-Records-2022-1/dp/1913484114/ref=zg-bs_books_1/261-5455843-9162427?pd_rd_w=vedUN&pf_rd_p=c3077bff-a471-42bf-a406-b93ec8e1a044&pf_rd_r=G24WF6JCCS60QFBJ54J3&pd_rd_r=b3faca64-d7e3-44a1-9bf8-0c454278bdff&pd_rd_wg=KvFlN&pd_rd_i=1913484114&psc=1

with Safari.

I am very new to all of this but I have spent hours pouring over guides and help with no success.

I have used 'inspect' to find the ID of the button which it says is 'Buy-Now-Button'

So that it is easy for me to test I already have the product page of what I want to buy open in Safari in the background.

Then I run the following script:

tell application "Safari"

```
activate

delay 2

do JavaScript "document.getElementById'buy-now-button').click();" in document 1
```

end tell

When I run this script it switches to Safari then nothing happens.  No error messages or anything just nothing.  I have tried it by the name rather than the ID but I just don't know what is going wrong.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help this is my first post.  I have put in a specific URL now.

Comment: Thats really odd it definitely takes me to a pirate ship with a buy now button.  Ill change the URL in case its just not available in certain areas.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guinness-World-Records-2022-1/dp/1913484114/ref=zg-bs_books_1/261-5455843-9162427?pd_rd_w=vedUN&pf_rd_p=c3077bff-a471-42bf-a406-b93ec8e1a044&pf_rd_r=G24WF6JCCS60QFBJ54J3&pd_rd_r=b3faca64-d7e3-44a1-9bf8-0c454278bdff&pd_rd_wg=KvFlN&pd_rd_i=1913484114&psc=1

Comment: You are a super star thank you so much that worked and took me much further on in my big project!  Only two more buttons to manage to work out how to click now!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the opening `(` in, `document.getElementById'buy-now-button')`:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById'buy-now-button').click();" in document 1
```

So, the following two examples work for me:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('buy-now-button').click();" in document 1
```

And:

```
tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('a-button-input')[1].click();" in document 1
```